# How to get the array for an Enum model attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I wanted to get the array of symbols(:foo,:bar) available in an Enum field(:status).

```
   class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
     enum status: [:foor, :bar]
   end
```

Comment: look at this guide here http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: `MyModel.statuses.keys.map(&:to_sym)`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As explained in the [Enum guide](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), if you have an enum field called `status` you access the mapping using the plural form:

```
MyModel.statuses
 => {"foor"=>0, "bar"=>1}
```

The keys are the enum values, the values are an incremental integer assigned based on the order of the enum definition.